# Ant publisher properties in JBoss Runtime on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-3.6

I am using JBoss 4.2 Runtime on Eclipse Helios. As you know it uses the build file (jboss323.xml) that comes with the plugin. However I want to change the way this build file behaves for a particular project (for example: override its WAR building process, say add a filter to exclude certain files). But I don't want to edit jboss323.xml file to do this, this would surely impact build process of other projects. Whats is the best way to achieve this?

P.S. I notice a configuration section called "Ant publisher properties" for JBoss Server runtime however there is no search-able documentation on what it does or how it has to be used. Can this filed be used to override the default build file, if so how?

Comment: Anybody had a solution ?

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work?